# javascript storing key value inside object

Tags: javascript

I have some json strings that look like that:

```
var TheJson = "{Key:[array of objects]}"
```

Key is actually a date and the json contains arrays of objects. I want to add this object to another object `HistoryOfData`, sort of like the `.push` method on arrays. Basically, I want the `HistoryOfData` object to have key value nested objects where the keys are dates and the values are arrays of data.

How do I push an object into another object?

Comment: The JSON string would have to be parsed into a real Object first. (see [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: indeed, but once I have the object from json, how do I push it to HistoryOfData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set them in the new object. Example:

```
var json1 = '{"06/08/2012": [{}, {"x": 1}, {"y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 4}]}';
var json2 = '{"06/10/2012": [{}, {"x": 5}, {"y": 6}, {"x": 7, "y": 8}]}';
var new_obj = {}, temp;

temp = JSON.parse(json1);
for(key in temp)
    new_obj[key] = temp[key];

var temp = JSON.parse(json2);
for(key in temp)
    new_obj[key] = temp[key];

console.log(new_obj); // Has two keys, each key is a date 
                      // and the values are Arrays of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in JSON.parse(TheJson)) {
  HistoryOfData[key] = TheJson[key]
}
```

`JSON.parse` is needed if TheJson is really still a String, and hasn't yet been turned into a JS Object.